# Locally finite cell complex are locally path connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Definition 1** : A cell complex is a Hausdorff topological space $K$ such that :

1. $K$ is a disjoint union of cell $e_i$ : $K=\cup_I e_i$.
2. Each cell is homeomorphic to the interior of the $m-$ closed unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^m$ for a $m \in \mathbb{N}$.
3. $K^m$ is the union of cell of dimension $m$ or less. We call $K^m$ the $m-$skeleton of $K$.
4. for each cell $e_i$ there exist $f_i : D^m \to K^m$ ($D^m$ is the closed unit ball) such that the restriction of $f_i$ to the interior of $D^m$ is an homeomorphism on $e_i$. And $f_i(S^{m-1}) \subset K^{m-1}$.

**Definition 2** : A cell complex $K$ is finite iff the number of its cells is finite.

**Definition 3** : $L$ is a subcomplex of $K$ iff :

1. $L$ is a union of cells from $K$.
2. For all cell $e$, if $e \subset L$ then $\overline{e} \subset L$.

**Definition 4** : A cell complex $K$ is locally finite if for all $x\in K$, there exist a finite subcomplex $L$ of $K$ such that $L$ is a neighborhood of x.

I need to show that a locally finite cell complex is locally path connected.

Thanks for your attention.

Edit : I add an extract from a document which highlight the difference between a CW complex (from Hatcher's book for example) and a cell complex like in **Definition 1**.[image]

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Let $x \in K$, let $V$ a neighborhood of $x$, and $L$ a finite subcomplex neighborhood of $x$. I have tried to find a neighborhood of $x$, include in $L \cap V$. But i'm stuck, I know that cells in $L$ are path connected as a direct image of  a continuous function of path connected set but the cells are disjoint so it doesn't seems to help for the proof. I can show that the closure of  cells are path connected too with the same argument but i don't really know how to construct a neighborhood from this.